# Azure Startup run book stop working, not sure what happened?

Tags: powershell, azure, runbook

The following script below worked for awhile, not sure why I keep getting this error:

**Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN doesn't exist.
Parameter name: name**

...etc..

**Get-AzureVM : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to 
set the default subscription.
At RICSVMStartup:13 char:13**

Here's the powerscript:

```
workflow RICSVMStartup
{
    # Grab the credential to use to authenticate
    $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'AzureCredential'

    #Connect to Azure
    Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred

    #Select the Azure subscription you want to work against
    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN"

    # Get all Azure VMs in the subscription that are not stopped and deallocated and shut down
    inlinescript
    {
        Get-AzureVM | where{$_.status -ne 'Started' -and $_.name -like 'RICS*' -and $_.name -ne 'RICSDC2'} | start-AzureVM 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, you must have a `server administrator` account and create a AD account, set the new AD Account as co-administrator in `SETTING>Administrators`, set the new AD account as credential in `Automation>ASSET`, and run your code: `$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'your new AD account'`. The above answer refers to more information links.

Comment: I had already setup the AD user...I tried to login to see if the password changed...seems like the issue relates to the user needing to be assigned a subscription.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out! Thank you so much, fixed the issue.

Comment: I just see your question now, you need to set your new AD account as co-administrator. I am glad that you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter these errors when using Live Id as the credential to connect to Azure. The solution is to use Azure Active Directory OrgID credential-based authentication, please follow the steps in [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/blog/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/) to create an Azure AD user and then use the OrgId to create the Automation credential asset.

For more information, please refer to this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/055f9830-3bf1-48f4-908b-66ddbdfc2d95/authenticate-to-azure-via-addazureaccount-with-live-id?forum=azureautomation